ContainerPausingBackOffHandler never called
My test setup publishes a single message on the topic "someTopic" and ensures that processMessages keeps throwing RuntimeExceptions and the ExponentialBackOff works as expected but I never see any method of ContainerPausingBackOffHandler or ListenerContainerPauseService being called. How do I pause the container via ContainerPausingBackOffHandler? Is this not supported for batches or maybe only if a BatchListenerFailedException is thrown?
Configuration:
    @Bean
    TaskScheduler listenerTaskScheduler() {
        var taskScheduler = new SimpleAsyncTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.setVirtualThreads(true);
        return taskScheduler;
    }

    @Bean
    ListenerContainerPauseService listenerContainerPauseService(
            KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry, TaskScheduler listenerTaskScheduler) {
        return new ListenerContainerPauseService(registry, listenerTaskScheduler);
    }

    @Bean
    ExponentialBackOff exponentialBackOff() {
        var backOff = new ExponentialBackOff();
        backOff.setInitialInterval(2000L);
        backOff.setMaxInterval(120000L);
        backOff.setMultiplier(2.0);
        return backOff;
    }

    @Bean
    DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler(
            ExponentialBackOff exponentialBackOff, ListenerContainerPauseService listenerContainerPauseService) {
        return new DefaultErrorHandler(
                null, exponentialBackOff, new ContainerPausingBackOffHandler(listenerContainerPauseService));
    }

    @Bean
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> customKafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> byteArrayKafkaConsumerFactory,
            DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        var factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configurer.configure(factory, byteArrayKafkaConsumerFactory);
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        return factory;
    }

Listener method
    @KafkaListener(
            autoStartup = "false",
            topics = "someTopic",
            containerFactory = "customKafkaListenerContainerFactory",
            concurrency = "8",
            batch = "true",
            clientIdPrefix = "prefix")
    @Override
    public void accept(List<Message<byte[]>> messages, Acknowledgment ack) {
         processMessages(messages);
    }


Any chances for some simple project we can run on our side to reproduce the problem? Thanks
